# button hover no longer works after move animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create two buttons that will move up when clicked. My problem is that after the animation occurs, the hover animation for the buttons no longer work. From my research I have gathered that it is something to do with `animation-fill-mode: forward` but I have found no solution that will allow the buttons to animate properly. Here is my relevant code

https://jsfiddle.net/kaizerroll987/j4owy2x7/#&togetherjs=qrfIRBIkon

Comment: better if you can share a jsfiddle link

Comment: here is a jsfiddle link, keep in mind however that I downloaded Animate.css and edited it. that is where the "justUp" function is written.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kaizerroll987/8qu0yLs3/1/#&togetherjs=1xpmB6S7MM

Comment: So this is very confusing. In the original code posted, there is no hover state at all. Putting that in my own fiddle, I dont have the opportunity to hover after click because your buttons are gone...but again...no hover effect to begin with(look at your css) However, in the fiddle you posted, it doesnt make sense. There is no animation on click. =/ I can fix your problem(as Im sure a lot of people can) but can you get a solid thing for us to look at?

Comment: Also, in the code posted, you define the same keyframes twice but with different values.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my comment. I added a framework - Animation.css to my code. that is where the css from the original code is written. It is was impractical to put that in my original jsfiddle so that is why it's not there.  As for why there are two keyframes written with the same name, it follows the same format as every other animation in Animate.css. I am fairly new to web development so I just tried to stick to what I saw. Here is a cdn for Animate.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Forward animations will cause the element to retain the style values from the last keyframe when the animation ends. Simple remove the `animation-fill-mode` attribute and your `hover` animation should work.

Comment: my issue is that when I remove the animate-fill-mode, the buttons return to their original position. I need some way to make the buttons retain their position without having the hover animation overwritten. Like some way to end the animation but maintain the positioning.

Comment: @TomKaizer You can set the buttons' style attributes after the animation is complete.

Comment: what would be a practical way to share the code with you including the 3200+ line animate.css file? I'd love to share it and get this solved I'm just having a hard time finding a practical way to share it. I'd just zip it up and share it that way but that doesn't seem to be an option on StackOverflow.

Comment: @TomKaizer You can put it in a JSFiddle.

Comment: done. I just took what I was using from one of the two css files and pasted it into the other.

Answer (score 0):

Im gonna take a random stab. There is a severe lack of info here...

On hover, set animation-name or I guess maybe animation-fill-mode to none.

```
.elem:hover {
    whatever: settings-you-want;
    animation-name: none;

}
```

I just did something similar.
The animation will take priority over hover.